# Is there any option in leaflet to stitch few image together and display

Tags: leaflet

I am want to write a web app that involves navigating technical illustrations (pan, zoom) , for that i used a sample [for that i used a sample](https://gist.github.com/longhotsummer/ba9c96bb2abb304e4095ce00df17ae2f)
 to display a non tile image using leaflet.

Now i need to input 3 or 4 image and it should stitch and diplay together and could use the technical illustrations (pan, zoom).

Could you please help me to find a solution.

Comment: What prevents you from using one ImageOverlay per image, with common border to achieve the stitch?